# Using Django template logic to determine if a object gets shown or not

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates

I want to be able that if the user chooses `Not public` as his dropdown option, that the post doesn't get shown, if it is `Public` it gets shown.

Code of index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% for post_object in object_list %}
      {% if post_object.choices == "Public" %}
        <h1>{{ post_object.post_title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ post_object.post_description }}</p>
      {% else %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </body>
</html>
```

models.py code:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField("Post title", max_length=200)
    post_description = models.TextField("Small description of your post")
    post_summary = models.TextField("Post summary")
    post_public = models.CharField(max_length=300, choices=[('Not public', 'Not public'), ('Public', 'Public')], default="Not public")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title
```

How do i know what current option the user choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the queryset for public posts like this.

```
Post.objects.filter(post_public='Public')
```

similarly for private posts:

```
Post.objects.filter(post_public='Not public')
```

Comment: I choose your solution. Worked really well! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I will just assume that you don't need a frontend form, as described in your title. I won't complete your views for you, but I'll give you the guidelines on how to do it.

Back to the topic, it will be easier to have everything handled first in the backend as, as things get complicated, Python is much powerful than the Jinja2 template syntax.

1. In your views, return a queryset *that returns every post but filter out the private ones*. That's also [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api-reference).
2. Render the remaining posts into your template.